# Private MWAA - Snowflake Connection Issue - Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow, mwaa

I set up an private Airflow environment in AWS -v2.2.2-.
Environment and plugins are up and running, I want to connect to Snowflake but I am getting the error below . -whl files in plugins.zip using requirements.txt-

```
snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='......snowflakecomputing.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/v1/login-request?request_id=....... (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at >, 'Connection to ........snowflakecomputing.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))
```

Same connection works in public mwaa.
I am adding connection informations into admin-connections tab from the UI
I know private env does not have connection to internet

I am aware i need to add some kind of outbound rule or endpoint but couldn't figure out .
Checked the endpoints and couldn't see anything related to Snowflake.
I will also be connecting to postgres, mysql DB's and few API's, which currently fails also

Is there a 1 click solution like adding some kind of outbound rule or should i be applying everything 1by1, and what would be that ?

If i want to connect to google-api something new, for snowflake something new etc ?

Also private mwaa environment is running on an existing vpc that has igw attachment, but the subnets that mwaa is running doesn't have any igw or nat attachment -as documentation suggests-

Comment: Are you referring to Privatelink connections? That would require you to use a Snowflake account that has Privatelink enabled and configured which means account URL contains **privatelink** as well.

Comment: I think i do? Do i setup privatelink for every service that i am going to use ? Also not sure if it is possible but what if a servise is not supporting Privatelink ?

Comment: AWS Privatelink is between VPCs not directly between services. Have a look [here](https://aws.amazon.com/privatelink/) to see how it works.

Comment: allright then privatelink is not useful for me, then how can i connect to API's and snowflake from my private network mwaa ?

Comment: Private network MWAA probably means you need privatelink, that's how AWS communicates between VPCs without routing via the public internet.